# Open and Run Excel Macro Automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have an xlsm file containing the code to be run daily at a specific time. Our IT policy blocks the usage of Windows Task Scheduler. Is there a way to open the xlsm file automatically at a specific time? As usual, Thanks a lot to this forum to always come into rescue!!

Comment: By the way, my organization does not allow installation of third party applications to trigger the file. I am looking out for solutions within excel/VBA. Thanks!

Comment: If the workbook is open 24/7 then the answer is "yes". Otherwise the answer is "no". If your organization doesn't allow its workers to do what they need to do, the organization is dysfunctional. Perhaps you could ask them for an approved workaround. For example, they could exercise their administrative privileges to schedule it for you. There are almost certainly scheduled tasks already on your machine and your IT department is perfectly able to schedule one more.

Comment: Thanks John! This macro will be on a remote machine. I can keep it open as long as my remote session is active. I will try working with my administrator for an exception.

Comment: [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime) is the method for scheduling tasks on a running instance of Excel. It can be hooked to `Workbook_Open` so the scheduling is automatically initialized whenever the workbook is opened.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if excel force closes after logging off from the remote machine. If it does not, then the problem is solved. I can use OnTime method. If not, then the Task Scheduler is the only way out.

Comment: Just experiment. Good luck.